# How to Change datatype of a Column in a temporary table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

Is there any way to change(increase) the data type of a column while saving the values into a temporary table?

```
SELECT TableA.ID_NO, sum(TABLEA.COST * TABLEB.QTY) as TOTAL
INTO #matCalc
FROM TABLEA A 
INNER JOIN TABLEB 
ON A.ID_NO = B.ID_NO
```

We have a bigger calculation in the actual query. When we execute our stored proc we get an error "arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric".

Any solution is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just explicitly cast the numeric as a larger type. I'm using 18,2 as an example, but I don't know your data, so different precision / scale may work better for you:

```
SELECT TableA.ID_NO, 
  SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), TABLEA.COST) * TABLEB.QTY) as TOTAL
INTO #matCalc
FROM TABLEA A 
INNER JOIN TABLEB 
ON A.ID_NO = B.ID_NO;
```

Comment: I want to convert Text datatype to char or varchar. I do the same but it gives an error.

Comment: @lazzy_ms I can't see what you are trying to do or what error you're getting. Perhaps you want to search for the error message and if you can't find anything create your own question with those specifics.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Create Table #matCalc(
ID BIGINT NULL,
TOTAL BIGINT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #matCalc
SELECT TableA.ID_NO, sum(TABLEA.COST * TABLEB.QTY) as TOTAL
FROM TABLEA A 
INNER JOIN TABLEB 
ON A.ID_NO = B.ID_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Temporary Tables as:

> Use appropriate data types such as you may want NUMERIC(18,2) for
>   TOTAL

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(
ID BIGINT NULL,
TOTAL BIGINT NULL
)

DELETE FROM @TempTable
INSERT INTO @TempTable
SELECT TableA.ID_NO, sum(TABLEA.COST * TABLEB.QTY) as TOTAL
FROM TABLEA A 
INNER JOIN TABLEB 
ON A.ID_NO = B.ID_NO
```

Comment: That's not a temporary table - it's a **table variable**

Comment: @shakir so can I similarly create a temporary table and make it work or is there a dynamic way of making such a conversion?

Comment: @Ranjith : You can always create a temporary table and doing dynamic conversion was a new addition to my knowledge. Go and see the answer that's marked by the questioner. It does what you want.